# Problems installing JBoss tool 3.3 on Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

i'm having problems installing jboss tools 3.3 on eclipse indigo. To be more precise i'm using:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release

I hav to install this for class, so i'm following this installation tutorial that was given: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3

When i try to install (i only need the Maven Support e Web and Java EE Development packages) i get the following errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: JBoss JAX-RS Tools 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2        (org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.feature.feature.group 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2)
 Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550     (epp.package.jee 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Debug UI 3.7.102.v20111129-1423_r372 (org.eclipse.debug.ui 3.7.102.v20111129-1423_r372)
Debug UI 3.7.0.v20110518 (org.eclipse.debug.ui 3.7.0.v20110518)
Debug UI 3.7.101.v20110817_r371 (org.eclipse.debug.ui 3.7.101.v20110817_r371)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (epp.package.jee 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.0.20110615-0550]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f)
To: org.eclipse.debug.ui [3.7.0.v20110518]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: JBoss JAX-RS Tools 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2 (org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.feature.feature.group 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2)
To: org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.ui [1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: JBoss JAX-RS Tooling (UI) 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2 (org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.ui 1.2.2.v20120323-1522-H83-Beta2)
To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui [3.7.101,3.8.0)
```

Anyone have an idea of what can i do t get this going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

upgrade your eclipse into 3.7.2 and install.

Refer here http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

FYI
Jboss tools 3.3 is not a stable release.  So it is better to use JBoss Tools 3.2.2.Final Stable Release  with Eclipse 3.6.2.